# How do I make Mathematica nest argument changes?

Tags: functions, recursion, iterators

I want something like Nest[f,x,n], but what where f is an argument change like a pushforward and x[t] is a function, for example, symbolically, and not in any sort of code:

$$
F{x[t]} \equiv x[2t + 1] - x[t-2]
$$

applied twice yields

$$
F{F{x[t]}} = x[4t + 3] - x[2t - 3] - x[2t - 1] + x[t - 4]
$$

I would love for Mathematica to give me the $n$th such application of $F$.

Pardon if this is a repeat question, nothing came up after a preliminary (but admittedly cursory) search.

Comment: Please use `Mathematica` notation, so as to disambiguate $x(2t + 1)$ which could either mean `x[2 t + 1]` or `x (2 t + 1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one out:

```
Simplify[Nest[# /. x[t_] :> x[2 t + 1] - x[t - 2] &, x[t], 2]]
```

Instead of applying a function, I repeatedly apply replacement rules to transform `x`.

We can also define `x` as a recursive function:

```
x[t_, 1] := x[t]
x[t_, n_] := x[2 t + 1, n - 1] - x[t - 2, n - 1]
x[t, 2]
```

Or define an operator `f` that acts recursively on an arbitrary function:

```
f[0] = Identity;
f[n_] := Function[x, f[n - 1][x][2 # + 1] - f[n - 1][x][# - 2] &]
f[2][x][t]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is great...I was trying to do something like this with /., but I knew that there must have been an easier way of doing it. This will be very helpful for me in many applications, I appreciate it very much! Edit: your edit is even more helpful still. Thanks very much again!